# Android Instrumented Test sometimes working and sometimes failing on generating coverage

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, android-testing, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm currently having a weird problem on generating instrumented test coverage and emma report using `connectedAndroidTest`. When I run `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` it sometimes work and generates the report and sometimes not.

When I run via `adb shell am instrument` it always work, but the problem is that I need to get the `.ec` file to unify with the unit test report automatically. I didn't change anything from one trial the the second one.

***Output:***

```
MacBook-Pro:test-android dimas$ ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

> Configure project :app
OneSignal Warning: Could not get AGP plugin version

> Task :app:kaptDebugAndroidTestKotlin
Annotation processors discovery from compile classpath is deprecated.
Set 'kapt.includeCompileClasspath = false' to disable discovery.
Run the build with '--info' for more details.

> Task :app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport FAILED

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 8 tests on Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.
> java.io.IOException: No coverage data to process in directories [/Users/.../app/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
61 actionable tasks: 13 executed, 48 up-to-date
MacBook-Pro:test-android dimas$ ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

> Configure project :app
OneSignal Warning: Could not get AGP plugin version

> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Starting 8 tests on Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 56s
61 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 59 up-to-date
```

Those are my Gradle DSL settings for:

***Android related***

```
defaultConfig {
       ...
       testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       ...
    }

buildTypes {
    all {
        multiDexEnabled = true
        ...
    }

    getByName("debug") {
        isDebuggable = true
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        isTestCoverageEnabled = true

        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

***Jacoco***

```
/* Jacoco & Tests Related tasks */
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}
```

***Test***

```
testOptions {
    animationsDisabled = true
    unitTests.apply {
        isReturnDefaultValues = true
        isIncludeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

val sharedTestDir = "src/sharedTest/java"
sourceSets.getByName("test") {
    java.srcDir(sharedTestDir)
}

sourceSets.getByName("androidTest") {
    java.srcDir(sharedTestDir)
}
```

Does someone know how to make it work properly? it seems that `app:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport` internal task is being executed by gradle before actually having the tests done.

Comment: are you running multiple tests at once? (multiple emulators running?) I have similar issue and it seems when I have more emulators, this error happens more. Not noticeable when I have 1 emulator, but highly noticeable when I have 4 running in parallel.

Comment: @CheolhoJeon as you see on this line `Starting 8 tests on Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9` I'm running 8 tests, but in 1 emulator. Were you able to successfully run 1 test at a time?

Comment: Hi @DimasMendes, did you find any solution to this issue? Even I am facing the same.

Comment: @Kavita_p didn't find any yet, I think that's a bug to be solved in future updates

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade Gradle to 4.0.0 and Gradle Wrapper to 6.1.1 works for me

Comment: For me this only helped, when I was also not using the `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59653757/2657024